Activity transaction animation android
I want to use this animation when switching between activities in the Intent using Android Studio.
i.sstatic.net/90TWh8KN.gif

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating what you have so far and where exactly you have problems with. Also please remove either the [tag:java] tag or the [tag:kotlin] tag, depending on what tag you want to remain and in what language the solution should be.
